# Line to connect bars in Pine Tradeview code

Tags: pine-script

Please, help to write code for Pine Tradeview [see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31QMh.png).

Need to draw lines. 
Connect by line every M15 11:15 close bar every day. (by result it should looks like zig zag, but you can choose which bars(time) to connect)

I don't know Pine. So, please, help.

Comment: There's ZigZag script in default script in tradingview http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2019/11/29/0024/1758/1636062/62/60e1e021f6.jpg You may change it and you'll get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the current candle contains your timestamp `timestamp(year,month,dayofmonth,11,15)`
2. If yes, shift the previous x- and y-values to another variable, such as "prev_x" and save the current x- and y-values.
3. Draw a line with the line.new()-function and use the "prev_x", "prev_y", "x" and "y" variables.

All of the above functions are explained here: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/